# php:Can't find the column but it is in the database

Tags: php

I am having trouble figuring out what's wrong whit my code. The code is used to take out specific columns from 2 big tables from a database. But we also need to sum 1 specific value when after I have used the query.

The problem is in this part

```
  $query = substr($query, 4);
    $sql2 = "SELECT SUM(Forspris) FROM orderrad
    JOIN orderhuvud on orderhuvud.OrderKund = orderrad.Orderdatum
     where ". $query;
        echo $sql2;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo print_r($row);     }
```

this is the error i get:

> SELECT SUM(Forspris) FROM orderrad JOIN orderhuvud on orderhuvud.OrderKund = orderrad.Orderdatum where OrderKund = '15' AND Orderdatum between '2015-04-16' AND '2015-05-06'Unknown column 'orderrad.Orderdatum' in 'on clause'

but it longer up in the code it can find the column orderdatum in the query

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">

    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "garp";

    $conn = new mysqli ($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    /*    $query = $_GET['query']; */
        $orderkund = $_GET['Orderkundinput']; 
        $artikel = $_GET['Artikelinput']; 
        $startDate =$_GET['startDate']; 
        $endDate =$_GET['endDate'] ;

        $MCkys = "orderdatum";

        $min_length = 2;
        $artikelQuery="";
        $orderkundQuery="";
        if(strlen($artikel) >= $min_length){ 
            $artikel = htmlspecialchars($artikel); 

            $artikel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $artikel);
            $artikelQuery = " AND Artikelnr = '$artikel'";
        }
        if (strlen($orderkund) >= $min_length){ 
            $orderkund = htmlspecialchars($orderkund); 

            $orderkund = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $orderkund);
            $orderkundQuery = " AND OrderKund = '$orderkund'";
        }

        if (strlen($startDate) >= $min_length){ 
            $startDate = htmlspecialchars($startDate); 

            $startDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $startDate);
            $startDateQuery = " AND Orderdatum between '$startDate' ";
        }

        if (strlen($endDate) >= $min_length){ 
            $endDate = htmlspecialchars($endDate); 

            $endDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $endDate);
            $endDateQuery = "AND '$endDate'";
        }

        $query = $artikelQuery.$orderkundQuery.$startDateQuery.$endDateQuery;
        if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 
        $sql = "SELECT OrderHuvud.Ordernummer ,OrderHuvud.OrderserieIK ,OrderKund ,Fakturakund ,Orderdatum ,Erreferens ,Levereratvarde ,Radnummer ,Artikelnr ,Benamning ,Leveranstid ,Ursprungligtantal ,Levereratantal ,Forspris ,Bruttopris ,Varukostnad FROM garp.OrderHuvud left join garp.OrderRad on OrderHuvud.Ordernummer = OrderRad.Ordernummer where  OrderHuvud.OrderserieIK = 'K'" .$query;
        $raw_results = $conn->query ($sql);
            $row_cnt = false === $raw_results ? 0 : $raw_results->num_rows;
            echo " <p class='rows'> Numbers of rows loaded: $row_cnt </p>";
            if($row_cnt > 0){
       while($raw_result = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)){
           echo "<table class='table'><thead class='thead-light'><tr><th class='col'>".'Ordernummer'."</th><th class='col'>".'OrderserieIK'."</th><th class='col'>".'Orderkund'."</th><th class='col'>".'fakturakund'."</th><th class='col'>".'orderdatum'."</th><th class='col'>".'erreferens'."</th><th class='col'>".'leveratvarde'."</th><th class='col'>".'radnummer'."</th><th class='col'>".'artikelnr'."</th><th class='col'>".'benamning'."</th><th class='col'>".'leveranstid'."</th><th class='col'>".'Ursprungligtantal'."</th><th class='col'>".'Levereratantal'."</th><th class='col'>".'forspris'."</th><th class='col'>".'bruttopris'."</th><th class='col'>".'varukostnad'."</th></tr></thead>";
           echo "<tbody><tr><td>".$raw_result['Ordernummer']."</td><td>".$raw_result['OrderserieIK']."</td><td>".$raw_result['OrderKund']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Fakturakund']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Orderdatum']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Erreferens']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Levereratvarde']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Radnummer']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Artikelnr']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Benamning']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Leveranstid']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Ursprungligtantal']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Levereratantal']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Forspris']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Bruttopris']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Varukostnad']."</td></tr></tbody></table>";

       }
            }

            else{
       echo "No return";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
        }
    $query = substr($query, 4);
    $sql2 = "SELECT SUM(Forspris) FROM orderrad
    JOIN orderhuvud on orderhuvud.OrderKund = orderrad.Orderdatum
     where ". $query;
        echo $sql2;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo print_r($row);     }
        ?>
```

Column Names:

[image]

Comment: can you post your `orderrad` table snapshot here?

Comment: the pic is in the post now

Comment: Do you join the table `orderhuvud` afterwards in the query? because you select from a different table `orderrad`: `FROM orderrad where orderhuvud.OrderKund`

Comment: no i did not do that

Comment: I cannot see something wrong with your query!!!, go and double check your column names and tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Forspris) FROM orderrad where orderhuvud.OrderKund
```

Your table is `orderrad` and in your where you try to use another table (`orderhuvud`) but you need to join first in order to use it, or select from it.

```
SELECT SUM(Forspris) FROM orderrad 
JOIN orderhuvud on orderhuvud.your_column_to_match = orderrad.your_column_to_match
where orderhuvud.OrderKund = '15' AND orderhuvud.Orderdatum between '2015-04-16' AND '2015-05-06'
```

Above code will join your table. In order to join them you need to find this column that both tables share and is the same for them so you join them on this.

Just a really clear example, please don't hate for the w3school, this example is really really clear for inner join. Read more [here!!!](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: How do  i join them?

Comment: i changed the code to this  `$query = substr($query, 4);
    $sql2 = "SELECT SUM(Forspris) FROM orderrad
    JOIN orderhuvud on orderhuvud.OrderKund = orderrad.Orderdatum
     where ". $query;
        echo $sql2;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo print_r($row);`   : but now it can't finde Orderdatum

Comment: What is the "query" parameter? Can you saw me the echo of the $sql2?

Comment: i solved it by doing it like this `$query = substr($query, 4);
$sql2 = "SELECT OrderKund,Artikelnr, SUM(Forspris),SUM(Levereratantal) FROM orderhuvud
left JOIN orderrad on orderhuvud.Ordernummer = orderrad.Ordernummer
 where ". $query ." GROUP BY OrderKund,Artikelnr";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo print_r($row);     }` but thx for the help

Comment: Good job you fixed your join. In the previous one you tried to join with date which is not always a great idea. Glad if i helped a bit in solving your problem.